# psexec bat file execution on multiple systems

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec

I have a requirement to run a particular .bat file on multiple servers.

I am currently using:

> psexec -s @c:\list.txt -c c:\copy.bat /user:Domain\userName -p %PasswordVariable% -d

I am getting error such as:-
Error copying c:\copy.bat to remote system:
The file exists.

Please note that file never exists.

Am i doing anything wrong?

list.txt has multiple server names and to access say for example \server1\c$ - username password is required. Does that creating problem while copy? But i have given the username and password in psexec command itself.

Answer (score 2):

use psexec "-c -f" or "-c -v" qualifiers

Answer (score -1):

Check the windows\system32 directory for that file.  Usually, psexec copies the file into that path.  Use the -f option to ovwrwrite the batch file if it already exists